# Export MassFX simulation with FBX problem

Tags: export, 3ds-max

So I've create a simple scene in **3ds MAX** with a **box** and a **rectangle** with **Garment Maker Modifier**:[image]

Then I apply **MassFX Rigid Body Modifier** to the **box**, setting it as a **dynamic object**:
[image]

To complete my scene, I apply **mCloth Modifier** to my **rectangle**, leaving default settings:[image]

To start simulation I press **Start Simulation Button** in the **MassFX Toolbar**:
[image]

Finally, I want to export this scene using **FBX**.
To achieve this, I ****bake** all** the animation by pressing **Bake All button** *(not **Bake Selected**, but **Bake All**)*:

[image][image]

Then I export the whole scene as **FBX file**. The following **FBX Export Window** shows up: [image]

I make sure that i clicked the the **Animation** and **Bake Animation** checkboxes and click OK. It takes my computer suspiciously small amount of time to export.

To check if the exported file is fine, i open it in **FBX Review program**, but **no cloth simulation is animated** when I press play button. [image]

P.s. It is only about **simulated** objects , **dynamic** ones work fine.

Is there any way of exporting scene WITH simulation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, the simulation engine is not exportable

Comment: Any simulation engine is not exportable, or only massfx?

Comment: No simulation engine is exportable, but offcourse that does not mean there is no situation where theres a engine in both ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation is something your application does. This is part of the code of your software, it does not export. The part that runs your simulation is called a solver. There exists a possiblity that your target provides a solver. FBX just does not have containers to move this info. In general exporting a simulation is more complex than geometry or animation, because its harder to have consensus how things should work.

This does not mean it could not work, its just harder to get it to work. Its alsi a politics issue as well as a technical issue.

Answer (score -1):

export it as objSequence ............

Comment: Please exlain what you mean, for example by adding shreenshot(s). Just leave the leading `!` out, one with more rep can activate it for you.  And please suppose the reader does not know where `objSequence`can be found ... Not to forget: welcome!